# How to create in tablet mode in Activity with two Fragments 2 different Toolbars?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

I want (in tablet mode) create Activity with two Fragments (master - detail). Approximately should look like this [Activity with two different Toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CCiq.png)

The reason I have two different Toolbars: is that in the second Fragment (detail) I want Collapsing Toolbar, but in the first (master) Toolbar must not collapsing.

But the search didn't give any thoughts how to begin this task ((

Comment: If you have just 2 fragments as shown in pic then using Toolbar within CoordinateLayout in both fragment "CAN" work. U need to have 2 layout both having toolbar in it. But what I think can be the issue is which toolbar to be set as activities toolbar. But till u don't get any valid solution u can work over it.

Comment: do you think using two viewpager, each with their own fragment(master and detail) with their own toolbar will do the trick?